# access token and refresh token from oneTap sign in/up

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, access-token, refresh-token

I'm trying to get access token and refresh token from my app. I'm using one tap sign in but I cant seem to get the desired access and refresh tokens (for Oauth2) .One tap works just fine in both signIn/signUp. I tried using the following:
Module:

```
@Provides
fun provideOneTapClient(
    context: Context
) = Identity.getSignInClient(context)

@Provides
@Named("signInRequest")
fun provideSignInRequest(
    app: Application
) = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
    .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
        BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
            .setSupported(true)
            .setServerClientId(app.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
            .build()
    )
    .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
    .build()

@Provides
@Named("signUpRequest")
fun provideSignUpRequest(
    app: Application
) = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
    .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
        BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
            .setSupported(true)
            .setServerClientId(app.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
            .build()
    )
    .build()

@Provides
fun provideGoogleSignInOptions(
    app: Application
) = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(app.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
    .requestScopes(Scope(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR))
    .requestServerAuthCode(app.getString(R.string.web_client_id), true)
    .requestEmail()
    .build()

@Provides
fun provideGoogleSignInClient(
    app: Application,
    options: GoogleSignInOptions
) = GoogleSignIn.getClient(app, options)

@Provides
fun provideAuthRepository(
    auth: FirebaseAuth,
    oneTapClient: SignInClient,
    @Named("signInRequest")
    signInRequest: BeginSignInRequest,
    @Named("signUpRequest")
    signUpRequest: BeginSignInRequest,
    signInClient: GoogleSignInClient,
    usersRef: CollectionReference
): AuthRepository = AuthRepositoryImpl(
    auth = auth,
    oneTapClient = oneTapClient,
    signInRequest = signInRequest,
    signUpRequest = signUpRequest,
    signInClient = signInClient,
    usersRef = usersRef
)
```

AuthImpl:

```
override suspend fun oneTapSignInWithGoogle() = flow {
    try {
        emit(Loading)
        val result = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest).await()
        emit(Success(result))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(Failure(e))
    }
}

override suspend fun oneTapSignUpWithGoogle() = flow {
    try {
        emit(Loading)
        val result = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signUpRequest).await()
        emit(Success(result))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(Failure(e))
    }
}

override suspend fun firebaseSignInWithGoogle(googleCredential: AuthCredential) = flow {
    try {
        emit(Loading)
        val authResult = auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential).await()
        val isNewUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser
        emit(Success(isNewUser))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(Failure(e))
    }
}
```

viewmodel:

```
override suspend fun oneTapSignInWithGoogle() = flow {
    try {
        emit(Loading)
        val result = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest).await()
        emit(Success(result))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(Failure(e))
    }
}

override suspend fun oneTapSignUpWithGoogle() = flow {
    try {
        emit(Loading)
        val result = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signUpRequest).await()
        emit(Success(result))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(Failure(e))
    }
}

override suspend fun firebaseSignInWithGoogle(googleCredential: AuthCredential) = flow {
    try {
        emit(Loading)
        val authResult = auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential).await()
        val isNewUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser
        emit(Success(isNewUser))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(Failure(e))
    }
}
```

SignIn Screen:

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            val credentials = viewModel.oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.data)
            val googleIdToken = credentials.googleIdToken
            val googleCredentials = getCredential(googleIdToken, null)
            viewModel.signInWithGoogle(googleCredentials)
        } catch (it: ApiException) {
            print(it)
        }
    }
}

fun launch(signInResult: BeginSignInResult) {
    val intent = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(signInResult.pendingIntent.intentSender).build()
    launcher.launch(intent)
}

when (val oneTapSignInResponse = viewModel.oneTapSignInState.value) {
    is Loading -> ProgressBar()
    is Success -> oneTapSignInResponse.data?.let {
        LaunchedEffect(it) {
            launch(it)
        }
    }
    is Failure -> oneTapSignInResponse.e?.let {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            print(it)
            if (it.message == "16: Cannot find a matching credential.") {
                viewModel.oneTapSignUp()
            }
        }
    }
}

when (val oneTapSignUpResponse = viewModel.oneTapSignUpState.value) {
    is Loading -> ProgressBar()
    is Success -> oneTapSignUpResponse.data?.let {
        LaunchedEffect(it) {
            launch(it)
        }
    }
    is Failure -> oneTapSignUpResponse.e?.let {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            print(it)
        }
    }
}

when (val signInResponse = viewModel.signInState.value) {
    is Loading -> ProgressBar()
    is Success -> signInResponse.data?.let { isNewUser ->
        if (isNewUser) {
            LaunchedEffect(isNewUser) {
                viewModel.createUser()
            }
        } else {
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                navController.navigate(EisenhowerScreens.EisenHomeScreen.name) {
                    popUpTo(EisenhowerScreens.LoginScreen.name) {
                        inclusive = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    is Failure -> signInResponse.e?.let {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            print(it)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using jetpack compose for the app. and I'm not sure what I need to have Access and Refresh tokens.
**Update:**
Apparently I cannot use one tap sign in to get access and refresh token for it is solely for authentication and it cannot take additional scopes etc

Comment: Most likely, your code is inspired by this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d). However, I don't fully understand what "access token and refresh token" means. According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions), *Firebase ID tokens are short lived and last for an hour; the refresh token can be used to retrieve new ID tokens.*.

Comment: I want to get google access and id tokens. so I can connect to google api on behalf of the user. since I do use onetap for google, I want to get Access and refresh which can be seen in this [site](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access)

Comment: So you want to authenticate on behalf of the user?

Comment: Basically when user signs up, They accept permissions(scopes), Which should give necessary parameters that is then saved in the server. So when user does an action. Cloud functions use the saved parameters to access and edit (in user google account) what it needs.